# Pandas KeyError: [''] not in index when merging two data frames from csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 dfs where the second df had 3 extra columns but the rest are the same. When I attempt to the merge the dfs I get the following error in row 4 of merge code - **df4 = df4[cols]**:

> KeyError: "['Product Name' 'Sales Price' 'Batch Name'] not in index"

Below is are the columns for each df:

[image]

My code is below:

**df2**

```
file = "non-payment-data.csv"
path = root + file
name_cols = ['GUID1','GUID2', 'Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name']
pull_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name']
df2 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col=False)

Data columns (total 5 columns):
Org ID          10 non-null object
Org Name        10 non-null object
Product Name    10 non-null object
Sales Price     10 non-null int64
Batch Name      10 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(4)
```

**df3**

```
file = "payment-data.csv"
path = root + file
name_cols = ['GUID1', 'Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name', 'Payment Amount', 'Transaction Date', 'Add Date']
pull_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name', 'Payment Amount', 'Transaction Date', 'Add Date']
df3 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col=False)

  Data columns (total 8 columns):
Org ID              9 non-null object
Org Name            9 non-null object
Product Name        9 non-null object
Sales Price         9 non-null int64
Batch Name          9 non-null object
Payment Amount      9 non-null int64
Transaction Date    9 non-null object
Add Date            9 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(6)
```

**Merge**

```
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='left', on=['Org ID', 'Org Name'])
cols = ['Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name', 'Payment Amount', 'Transaction Date', 'Add Date']
df4 = df4[cols]
df4.head()

Data columns (total 7 columns):
Org Name            10 non-null object
Product Name        10 non-null object
Sales Price         10 non-null int64
Batch Name          10 non-null object
Payment Amount      0 non-null float64
Transaction Date    0 non-null object
Add Date            0 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(5)
```

I have tried the following based on research:

```
df4['Batch Name'] = fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True) #same for the other two
```

and

```
df4 = df4.reindex(cols=cols)
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @piRSquared df4 = df4[cols]

Comment: `df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='left', on=['Org ID', 'Org Name'])`, after this type `df4.columns` what you get ?

Comment: @Wen same thing. KeyError: "['Org Name' 'Product Name' 'Sales Price' 'Batch Name'] not in index"

Answer (score 3):

When you merged, there were  other column names in common.  Those columns get changed to include a suffix `_x` for the duplicate columns from the left and `_y` for duplicates from the right.

You can control the suffixes with the `suffixes` parameter

```
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='left', on=['Org ID', 'Org Name'], suffixes=['', '_'])
cols = ['Org Name', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Batch Name', 'Payment Amount', 'Transaction Date', 'Add Date']
df4 = df4[cols]
df4.head()
```

Comment: the error went away and i see all of the columns but the 3 that had the error now all come up as NaN

Comment: Then there is likely issues with your data and you haven't shared any of it.  I can't help you without it.

Comment: I added the pics of each table from when I do df.head()